# JSP Tutorial for ASP.Net Developer

Tags: asp.net, jsp

I am an ASP.Net developer looking to expand my dope skillz to the wonderful world of Java. Strangely, there seem to be a ton of "ASP.Net for the JSP Developer" tutorials, but very few (no?) "JSP for the ASP.Net Developer" tutorials. Just simple things like the difference between the file structures and layout, what webserver to use and how to configure it, etc... A thousand tiny differences add up to a frustrating experience that, no doubt, a single good tutorial could easily answer.

So... anyone know of a good tutorial? Or, short of that, what is the best "getting started" with JSP tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know any tutorials for that neither, but I know a little of both worlds (jsp and asp.net) and I recommend you two ways:

1st. If you just want to know the syntax differences, It might be a good try take a first look at this [JSP Overview](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/jsp/) by Sun and you will automatically map main differences (I do not recommend you to go this way because both platforms do not differ only on its syntax)

2nd. If you are going to develop Java Web Applications, you should take a first look [J2EE Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/) (specially in Part II) and also some MVC frameworks ([Struts](http://struts.apache.org/), [Spring Web MVC](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html)) and some 'different MVC approaches' [JSF](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/JSF_and_MVC).

JSP is a front-end technology, it is not a good practice to put business logic and/or complex code on it.

Hope it helps.